# How to get client ip from request metadata with grpc-java

Tags: java, grpc

I use grpc-java and get the metadata by ServerInterceptor, but i get below information without client ip address, the authority is server ip, how can i get the client ip?Thanks.

> Metadata({:scheme=[http], :method=[POST], :path=[/test/test1],
>   :authority=[192.168.199.9:50051], grpc-encoding=[identity],
>   grpc-accept-encoding=[identity,deflate,gzip], te=[trailers],
>   content-type=[application/grpc], user-agent=[grpc-objc/0.13.0
>   grpc-c/0.13.0 (ios)]})

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Client IP is not provided in Metadata. But you can call [ServerCall.attributes()](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/c3011b079874f9b5a598335e03400a67556e2def/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/ServerCall.java#L225) and get the [Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Grpc.html#TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR).

Please note that the API is unstable and may change.

Comment: How do I get REMOTE_ADDR_KEY in Stream Listener? Do I have to use ThreadLocal every time to fetch this information?

Comment: The pattern we'd suggest is to have a single central "auth policy" interceptor that would access REMOTE_ADDR_KEY and then put an object on the Context (which [Contexts.interceptCall()](http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Contexts.html#interceptCall-io.grpc.Context-io.grpc.MethodDescriptor-io.grpc.ServerCall-io.grpc.Metadata-io.grpc.ServerCallHandler-) makes relatively easy)

Answer (score 7):

if in python grpc, you will get client ip address and port using `context.peer()`.

```
def your_method(self, request, context):
    ...
    context.peer() # return 'ipv4:49.123.106.100:44420'
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

In latest (1.2.0) gRPC use `io.grpc.Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR` attribute in interceptor to get remote address.

Answer (score 3):

Client IP is exposed as gRPC attributes (TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR), an example of accessing it is [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/30b59885b7496b53eb17f64ba1d822c2d9a6c69a/interop-testing/src/main/java/io/grpc/testing/integration/AbstractInteropTest.java#L1650)

```
 String inetSocketString = serverCallCapture.get().getAttributes()
    .get(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR).toString();
```